# How to convert all data in column to datetime - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a large dataframe that, in its `date` column, has a mixture of date formats (only 2).

Most are in the correct format but there is some data that is in a different format.

i.e. most are `2013-11-07`. Some are `20170510`. Pandas throws an exception when i try to validate the code against a schema i have.

Is there a quick way to convert all dates to have the same format as the majority? Or do i have to do something more painful/manual?

i.e.

```
             date                      \
0            2013-11-07                False   
2            2013-11-07                False      
...               ...    ...    ...         ...                  ...   
3595037      20170510                  NaN   
3595038      20200701                  NaN
```

Comment: If use `pd.to_datetime(df.col)` not working?

Comment: no... it doesn't seem to convert yyyymmdd using that.. or it could be yyyy-mm-dd is the problem. I can't tell which one it doesn't like

Comment: Hmm, can you add some data sample which failed? Because for me working perfectly.

Comment: i added what i have

Comment: OK, so if add `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` it failed?

Comment: yes, it says "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()

RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise"

Comment: How working `pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str))` ? What is your pandas version?

Comment: 1.3.3 is my version

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a quick way to convert all dates to have the same format as the majority?*

Considering that you have only two formats, one represented by `2013-11-07` and another by `20170510` it is enough to remove `-` from first to get common format, i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':['2013-11-07','20170510']})
df['day'] = df['day'].str.replace('-','')
print(df)
```

output

```
        day
0  20131107
1  20170510
```

`pandas.to_datetime` does understand it correctly

```
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'])
print(df)
```

output

```
         day
0 2013-11-07
1 2017-05-10
```

Disclaimer: I converted to format of minority not majority. It is possible to convert that to format of majority using regular expression, however if you are interested in datetime objects, this is unnecessary complication.

Comment: Hmm, replace is not `this is unnecessary complication.` ? Why not use only `df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'])` ?

Comment: I get `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!` for the replace command.

Comment: i converted the column to strings initially. Will give your code a whirl and report back :)